# Undo alternate command definition

Tags: tex-core, paragraphs

I'm working with an automated system that injects some code that redefines the paragraph command:

```
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
```

I'm stuck with this change.

This causes issues with some LaTeX packages that I use below these lines.

Is there a simple way to un-do this action? Maybe

```
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\oldparagraph}
```

Comment: `\let\paragraph\oldparagraph` and `\let\subparagraph\oldsubparagraph`... But you shoud check if `\oldparagraph` and `\oldsubparagraph` are already defined like in the code above: `\ifx\oldparagraph\undefined\else\let\paragraph\oldparagraph\fi` and the same for `\subparagraph`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `\renewcommand{\paragraph}{\oldparagraph}` will do *if* `\paragraph` is defined to begin with.

Better is

```
\let\paragraph\oldparagraph
```

In case `\oldparagraph` is not defined, then your class doesn't allow `\paragraph` to begin with and you will get an error just like you'd get without the injected code.

By the way, that code is wrong and it should have

```
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}\par}
```

otherwise input such as

```
\paragraph{Title}
Something
```

will not have “Something” on a new line (but on the same line with a spurious space in addition) which is almost certainly what the redefinition is aiming to attain.